# How can the password be hidden from Firebug's Net panel?

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, firebug

I am a web developer and using Firebug to track my AJAX requests.
But some days back I came to know that every network request you do is tracked by Firebug not only asyncronous requests.

If you submit a form normally using the HTTP protocol (not an AJAX call), it is still logged in Firebug's *Net* panel and is shown openly.
I checked it on various reputable sites (names can't be disclosed) having SSL certificates and using the HTTPS protocol, though they are also having this problem.

Is there any technique to encrypt the password before a normal form submit?

Suppose I am using `$.ajax()`, then I can encrypt the password using base64, or my custom encryption technique, but what in case of normal HTTP submits?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open Firefox.
2. Start Firebug if you have it or install it, then start it.
3. Go to the *Net* panel in Firebug.
4. Open any website where you have an account and just log in with your credentials.
5. Just check the POST requests where you got your original password as a plain text.

Comment: Be aware that the person typing in the password can also see the password they are typing in! (With HTTPS this is only visible in the browser on the machine that's actually submitting the data. This is not something you can mitigate, nor should you worry about it)

Comment: aaaaand: base64 is not an encryption.it's an encoding! BIG difference.

Comment: @JoshuaK : yes sir, I agree with you that its not encryption. but is there any way to control over this..?

Comment: look at the comment of Alex K. there is no need of controling this. it's only availible at the client side... there is no way you can hide this and there is no need for it. It is not a security hole or risk or somethink like that. if you have further questions, pls edit your question so we understand at which point you are struggle

Comment: @JoshuaK : no sir. thanks.

Comment: Using JS you can hash the value of a field before sending it via HTTP/S. The server then needs to be able to un-hash the value when it is received. Depending on how you have hashed it, that may be impossible. So this will only work if A) the browser has JS enabled and B) the server is prepared to received a hashed value. So this will not work for just any website. I am concerned that you are missing what everyone is saying. The password is only shown to the user; when used with SSL, the communication between client and server is encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the password is shown in plain text only in the client and the server. If the server uses [TLS (formerly called SSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), then the data will be encrypted by the client before it is sent to the server and the server will decrypt it again.

So you don't need to worry about the password being shown in clear text in Firebug as long as the connection between client and server is encrypted.